# How can I add a file to my .gitignore without deleting it?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a configuration file in my project that is server specific so does not want to be included in Git as every time we deploy it overwrites the settings for the server. To resolve this problem the file was deleted from Git... nice idea but now every time the project is deployed the servers configuration file is deleted.

So I'm now stuck with a problem. What I really wanted was the file to be in `.gitignore` and never added to the project, but once it was added I can't see a way to remove it from the project without it firing off a delete on the existing file with every deploy.

Is there way I can remove a file from a project without deleting it. Effectively retrospectively ignoring a file that was already added?

Comment: How are you deploying?  Since you only mention git I'd infer that you deploy by a git pull; but that shouldn't behave the way you've described.  The pull *of the commit that deleted the file* might delete the file (though, if the local file didn't match the last version in git it should show up as a conflict); but after that, once the file is back in place, subsequent pulls (of commits that have no relationship to the file) shouldn't affect the file.  The file should show up as "untracked" unless you .gitignore it.  That said...

Comment: ...since the behavior you describe differs from what git should do, I suspect you're using some other method to deploy.  But if you *are* using some other method to deploy, then the fact that the file was once in git has no effect at all on the deployment process.  All that said, I will provide an answer that addresses the question as asked; but I think some clarification of this point would be useful.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger is right: Git will only *delete* the file on a `git checkout` that takes you from a situation where the config file is in the index and the work-tree, to a commit where the config file is is *not* present. However, every time you move to a commit that *does* have the file, then back to one that *does not*, Git will replace and remove the file (provided it's allowed to, either because there are no changes in index+work-tree, or because you used `--force`). Hence "how are you deploying" is a crucial question.

Answer (score 3):

The easy and safe way to address this is to add the files you want to exclude to `.gitignore`.

If the file is already being tracked (previously added and committed) you will also need to delete it from the repository. This can be done without deleting the local file which you want to keep by telling git to only delete the tracked version.

`git rm --cached <file>` is the command that will do this. When you commit that change along with the `.gitignore` update, the repository will stop tracking and start ignoring that file.

Comment: not right, when you checkout or switch to another branch and switch back, the ignored file will be removed, yes, from local.

Comment: So you are describing the same situation as if you'd never added a file to git in one branch but it exists in another branch? The advice lets you get the branch you are on forget about a file and start ignoring it. Other branches have to be handled separately. But that is what you'd expect from a branched repository.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "file was never checked in and is .gitignored" vs. "the file was checked in but then rm-ed and has since been .gitignored" is less than you're inferring.  *If* having never added the file and put it in .gitignore would've worked as expected, then having removed the file you can put it in .gitignore and, after possibly one round of difficulty, it should start working.

(That would be the case, for example, if you use `git pull` to update the server.  The pull *of the commit that deleted the file* might delete the file - though it should show up as a conflict.  But subsequent pulls would ignore the file, especially if you've since added it to .gitignore.  But I digress, and I've covered my confusion here in the comments...)

So the question was how to remove a file from history as though it had never been added, and while I doubt it will help, here is how you can do it:

You have to "rewrite" the commit (or commits) that introduced the file, as well as any commit descended from such a commit.  If this is a shared repository, then after the rewrite everyone will have to transition to the rewrite - most easily done by having everyone discard their current repo and re-clone.  This means you have to coordinate a "no change" window; if someone does make a change after the cut-off at the beginning of that window, it will need to be rebased into the rewritten tree.

Now if the file was added recently and not a lot of history exists after the commit that introduced it, then this might be a relatively simple process and you can even take some shortcuts.  But the *general* solution is to use either `git filter-branch` or the BFG Repository Cleaner.

Of the two, BFG is easier and faster (as this is one of the tasks it's specifically designed to address).  Its author believes the only safe procedure is to manually remove the file from current commits, test that everything in the current commit works as expected, and then use BFG to clean up history.  I think this is overly pedantic and have explained to him why, but he persists; so you would have to make up your own mind.

If you opt to use `filter-branch` you would use an index filter; it's one of the stock examples in the git filter documentation, so I'd just look it up there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git log --oneline` to print a list of commit logs and you fire up a `git reset 'head'` to unstage the files. Then you can apply the correct .gitignore template before committing the file.
 If you have not committed the files already you can use git rm --cached to unstage the files.
 You can find a collection of gitignore templates from this github page https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the unneeded file(s) in the `.gitignore` file. So that Git will ignore any changes to the specified file(s).

If you do not have the `.gitignore` file, you can simply create it, and type in the filename(s) to be ignored. Keep in mind that you will have to commit the `.gitignore` file once you add it to the repository. This will indicate Git to ignore the file(s) specified inside the `.gitignore` file.

In short and simple words. You create a file named `.gitignore` in your working repository and list there the file name or pattern to match
e.g. If we want to ignore all the `.sql` files. In the `.gitignore` We will type the following:

```
*.sql
```

If we want to ignore just a single file, lets say `lib/util.php`.
Then the `.gitignore` will look like this:

```
lib/util.php
```

You can specify multiple file names in .gitignore as you wish.

[gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Notice that this will work only in case the file was never tracked in the repository to begin with as correctly noted by @Mark Adelsberger and @torek.

Comment: If the file is already tracked (i.e., in the index), putting its path into a `.gitignore` has no effect. You must make the file *un*tracked, which the OP did. The problem is that then there is a `git checkout` path that gets you the (tracked, committed) file, followed by a `git checkout` of the later commit that *removes the file from the work-tree*. Once it's out of the index, all is OK, except that the file is gone from the work-tree: it must be restored from somewhere (such as the commit where it is present).